# Visual Studio 2012 not stopping at exception in debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

First off, i've looked at similar issues posted and they all seem to involve a 64 bit windows bug.  I'm running 32 bit though, on a local machine.  The application is a asp.net website with links to a number of libraries all contained inside the project solution.

I'm mainly trying to understand why visual studio would just pass by this exception during debug mode.  I believe it's getting generated in the CLR level, because when I enable  throwing at the CLR level then VS will stop and display the error.  But it won't let me step through the code to get to that error.  It's like a black box.  I'm breaking at the last known line of my code before the error happens.  I hit F11 once more and the code leaves the last line of my method and VS hangs while the application window displays:

[image]

Nothing pops up in VS.  As if it's not in debug mode.  When i enable throwing at the CLR level VS errors out sooner saying privileges to access this code is denied.

How does one intelligently go about debugging an issue like this?

Thanks,

Comment: what line of code is the `last known line of my code before the error happens`? is it always the same line?

Comment: always the same line.  I found the bug, which was an DateTime type parameter for a objectDataSource being mapped to an empty textbox.  I suspected something along these lines, just wish I knew of a better way to hone in on the issue.  The thing that peeves me is the objectDataSource is making a select() call, though the code would not stop on the select() event with a breakpoint.  Swear I've noticed this before, where controls make function calls yet don't trigger breakpoints in their event methods.  Kinda want to chalk it up to the twisting maze of the webforms page life cycle.  Who knows.

Comment: ...between the content page life cycle pinging back and forth to the masterpage life cycle pinging back and forth to the custom user controls life cycles, I can't keep it straight.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Web Application (vs web site) - check your project properties to produce full debug information

+

Menu Debug -> exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions set to "thrown"

  +

check in Options -> Debugging -> General

uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

+

"delete Assembly cache" from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files -- you may simply run a different version of dll

Comment: It's a web site.  And I've done the other suggestions you've mentioned, which result in a "Source not Available" frame and the same error message and call stack that I can see on the webpage.  Maybe i'm not seeing the value in this call stack.  Because what I see doesn't seem helpful.  All the functions are from System.Web.UI.  Controls are making operations, but there's no id's to identify which one.  Parameters are being passed, but the stack doesn't give their identity or values.  It's all very generic info that doesn't really narrow the problem down. Hopefully I'm missing the point here.

Comment: I forgot to mention "delete Assembly cache" from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files -- you may simply run a different version of dll